# Passing parameter to formType in symfony 2

Tags: forms, symfony

I have tables A and B(names are not important), one to many relationship, B contains A_id, I want to add a B record inserting A_id from a hidden field in the form, so I have:

index.html.twig (A)

```
 <a href="{{ path('B_new', { 'id': entity.id }) }}">Follow</a>
```

Bcontroller.php

```
public function newAction($id)
    {
        $entity = new B();
        $form   = $this->createCreateForm($entity, $id);

        return $this->render('UjcBundle:B:new.html.twig', array(
            'entity' => $entity,
            'form'   => $form->createView(),
        ));
    }
```

But I get an error:

```
Error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Symfony\Component\Debug\ExceptionHandler::handle() must be an instance of Exception, instance of Error given in E:\xampInstall\htdocs\nuevo\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Debug\ExceptionHandler.php:90
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: Symfony\Component\Debug\ExceptionHandler->handle(Object(Error))
#1 {main}
thrown in E:\xampInstall\htdocs\nuevo\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Debug\ExceptionHandler.php line 90
```

it seems problem is $id parameter in createCreateForm,

and then:

```
private function createCreateForm(B $entity, $id)
    {
        $form = $this->createForm(new BType($id), $entity, array(
            'action' => $this->generateUrl('b_create'),
            'method' => 'POST',
        ));

        $form->add('submit', 'submit', array('label' => 'Create'));

        return $form;
    }
```

Is there any better way to do this? createCreateForm $id parameter is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your error but if you need to provide additional data to a form I would define a new required option in your `configureOptions()` method (inside your `BType`):

```
 $resolver->setRequired('something_id');
```

In your controller:

```
$form = $this->createForm(new BType($id), $entity, array(
    'action' => $this->generateUrl('b_create'),
    'method' => 'POST',
    'something_id' => $id
));
```

and then in your `buildForm()` method you can access it via the `$options` variable: `$options['something_id']`

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

What are you doing with $id in BType?

I would do like this: remove $id from BType and createCreateForm. And:

```
#BController
newAction($id){
    $a = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:A')->findOneBy(['id' => $id]);
    $b = new B();
    $form = $this->createForm(BType::clasa, $b);
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()){
        $b->setA($a);
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($b);
        $em->flush();
    }
    return $this->render('...');
}
```